# How to select a transactional.id for a REST API that transactionally publishes to Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

We have a fleet of REST API servers that act as the entry-points to our event-sourced micro-service architecture. In several of these REST endpoints, we need to be able to atomically write to several Kafka topics. Our understanding is that [Kafka transactions](https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/) are the correct (and only) way to do this.

Our understanding of the transaction semantics are as follows:

- In order for Kafka transactions to work correctly, each producer must be assigned a `transactional.id`. This identifier acts as Kafka's internal token for this producer's transaction context.
- Each assigned `transactional.id` must always be occupied. If this were not the case, a consumer in `READ_COMMITED` mode would block on a topic if a transaction were started by a producer which later died, and whose `transactional.id` was not picked up by another node.
- Once any producer selects a `transactional.id` that is currently in use, Kafka increments that `transactional.id`'s epoch number, fences out any other producers that may be using that id and closes any open transactions with stale epoch numbers.

Most of the publicly available resources about transactional Kafka address the use-case of stream computation for commit logs which is *not* our use-case (we use `kafka-streams` for this). We specifically care about safely publishing data from *outside* Kafka.

Our Environment:

- We have a fluctuating number of REST API nodes and thus Kafka producers, based on service load and managed by ECS.
- We cannot easily predict in advance how many of any API nodes will be running.
- Identical API nodes will be publishing to identical topics.

Thus our questions are:

- How can we assign `transactional.id`s correctly in this context? Because of the nature of auto-scaling, we cannot use our node-number as a factor in the `transactional.id` because as soon as we reach a new high-water mark of nodes, any time we scale down, we risk having un-allocated `transactional.id`s floating around.
- Is our use-case appropriate for Kafka transactions or should we be doing something else to guarantee the semantics we need in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can still use a unique node id for your transactional.ids, and your use case seems appropriate for Kafka transactions.

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you're concerned that a Producer with a given transactional.id may unexpectedly fail and leave an open transaction lying around that will block consumers operating in read_committed mode. Normally, you might expect the Producer to come back to life an re-register its transactional.id, which would cause any open transactions to abort, but in your case, the Producer may simply never come back, due to a scale down in the number of your API nodes.

There are several configuration values that help with this situation. The main one is the producer config:

`transaction.timeout.ms`

which is the maximum time the transaction coordinator will wait for an update from a producer before aborting a transaction. The current default for that is 60000 ms, but you may wish to reduce it if it makes sense in your situation. After the transaction is aborted, consumers should become unblocked.

You may also be interested in the broker level configs:
`transactional.id.timeout.ms` and `transaction.abort.timed.out.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms`

See the Kafka doc for descriptions of these: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/

Or read the original KIP for a bit more detail: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-98+-+Exactly+Once+Delivery+and+Transactional+Messaging

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, your pipeline looks like this :

`Rest API -> Kafka producer (write atomically)-> Kafka cluster`

In order to write atomically in Kafka, using a KafkaProducer, you can enable producer idempotence ( that will use a cache Kafka side to avoid duplicates), and of course, use acks=all parameters ( this will ensure your records are written to at least some ISR).

Here some doc for idempotence producer :

https://www.cloudkarafka.com/blog/2019-04-10-apache-kafka-idempotent-producer-avoiding-message-duplication.html

Kafka transactions are useful when doing  Read Proccess Write inside a same Kafka cluster like the following :

`Kafka cluster --> read -- > KafkaConsumer -- Transform --> KafkaProducer --> same Kafka cluster`

If I'm correct, you don't need to use Kafka transactions, thus don't need to worry about transactionnal.id

Yannick

Comment: My understanding is that an idempotent producer will ensure that any given message will have EoS, but suppose we are sending a string of messages across multiple topics and want to be resilient to crashes in-between messages. Idempotent producers do not give us that?

Comment: Yeah you will have EoS producing. As soon as you're not fully in the Kafka cluster ( your data comes from external source, which is REST APIs here), it becomes tricky to be EoS in a distributed/ resilient fashion. Kafka garantees you EoS/transaction in a Read-Transfrom-Process when read data comes from the same Kafka cluster. This is not your case.Thus you will have to deal with "handling crash/resiliency" on your own. You can imagine storing the information that your producer did receive the ack when producing. but even with this you can have inconsistence ( crash while storing the info ..)